# Finding Minimum Values with Multiple Joins

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, left-join, minimum

I am using StandardSQL in BigQuery and have 7 tables with 10 to 75 columns each and thousands of rows. For simplicity I will only use the relevant tables and columns for what I am trying to accomplish.

Table 1

| Item | Desc |
| --- | --- |
| 12341 | abcd |
| 23451 | bcda |
| 34561 | cdab |
| 45671 | dabc |

Table 2

| SubItem | Location | ON_OFF | OnHand | OnOrder |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12345 | 1 | ON | 3 | 5 |
| 12345 | 2 | ON | 4 | 2 |
| 12345 | 3 | ON | 2 | 4 |
| 12346 | 1 | ON | 7 | 7 |
| 12346 | 2 | ON | 1 | 4 |
| 12346 | 3 | ON | 8 | 7 |
| 23451 | 1 | OFF | 1 | 1 |
| 23451 | 2 | OFF | 3 | 2 |
| 34567 | 1 | ON | 6 | 0 |
| 34567 | 2 | ON | 1 | 5 |
| 34568 | 1 | ON | 2 | 0 |
| 34568 | 2 | ON | 3 | 10 |
| 45671 | 2 | ON | 5 | 1 |

Table 3

| Item | SubItem |
| --- | --- |
| 12341 | 12346 |
| 23451 | 23451 |
| 34561 | 34567 |
| 34561 | 34568 |

Current Result

| Item | Desc | ON_OFF | OH | OO |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12341 | abcd | ON | 9 | 11 |
| 12341 | abcd | ON | 16 | 18 |
| 23451 | bcda | OFF | 4 | 3 |
| 34561 | cdab | ON | 7 | 5 |
| 34561 | cdab | ON | 5 | 10 |
| 45671 | dabc | ON | 5 | 1 |

Desired Result

| Item | Desc | ON_OFF | OH | OO |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12341 | abcd | ON | 9 | 18 |
| 23451 | bcda | OFF | 4 | 3 |
| 34561 | cdab | ON | 5 | 5 |
| 45671 | dabc | ON | 5 | 1 |

I am looking for the Minimum OH and Minimum OO Value for each item and as in the case of Item 45671, that does not correspond with the same SubItem number.

Current code providing me with the Current Result table is:

```
Select 
Table1.Item,
Table1.Desc,
Table2.ON_OFF,
Table2.OH,
Table2.OO
From Table1
Left Join Table3
On Table1.Item = Table3.Item
Left Join 
    (Select SubItem, ON_OFF, Sum(OnHand) As OH, Sum(OnOrder) As OO
        From Table 2
        Group by 1,2)
ON Table3.SubItem = Table2.SubItem;
```

Looking for ideas as I am still fairly new to SQL and the current actual code ties 7 tables with various joins to build a final table with 45 columns and thousands of rows. I have looked at using RowNumber() and Partition By, but I am not sure where it would go. Was also thinking separating the OO and OH into two joins might help.

Any suggestions welcome! Thank you!

Comment: Your problem statement and results don't match.  "18" is not the minimum OO value for the first item.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your sample data, It seems that You can use `group by` and aggregate function `min` as follows:

```
Select Table1.Item,
       Table1.Desc,
       Table2.ON_OFF,
       Min(Table2.OH),
       Min(Table2.OO)
  From Table1
  Left Join Table3
    On Table1.Item = Table3.Item
  Left Join (Select SubItem,
                    ON_OFF, 
                    Sum(OnHand) As OH,
                    Sum(OnOrder) As OO
               From Table2
              Group by 1,2) Table2
    ON Table3.SubItem = Table2.SubItem
Group by Table1.Item, Table1.Desc, Table2.ON_OFF;
```

Answer (score 0):

I worked with it after getting some much needed sleep...

I came up with the below and it is working!

```
SELECT T1.Item, 
 T1.Desc,
 T3_1.ONOFF, 
 T3_1.OH,
 T3_2.OO
 FROM Table1 T1

 Left Join
    (Select Item, SubItem,T2_1.O_O as ONOFF, T2_1.OH1 as OH,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Item ORDER BY T2_1.OH1) as rn
    FROM T2_1
    Left Join
      (Select SubItem, SUM(IFNULL(OnHand,0)) AS OH1,
      FROM  Table2 
      GROUP BY 1) T2_1
    ON T2_1.SubItem = T3_1.SubItem) T3_1
  On T1.Item = T3_1.Item
  
 Left Join
    (Select Item, SubItem, T2_2.OO1 as OO,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Item ORDER BY T2_2.OO1) as rn2
    FROM T2_2
    Left Join
      (Select SubItem, SUM(IFNULL(OnOrder,0)) AS OO1,
      FROM  Table2 
      GROUP BY 1) T2_2
    ON T2_2.SubItem = T3_2.SubItem) T3_2
  On T1.Item = T3_2.Item
 
 Where rn = 1 and rn2 = 1;
```

Thanks!

Comment: if you really think your answer does work  - please double check it - you might have some typos  - please fix it!